# How do I force threads to take turn concatenating to a string?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Basically I have 2 text files with each file having a bunch of lines all 1-character long. Each character in one file is a letter or zero, if the character is zero, I need to look at the other file to see what is supposed to be there. My goal is to start two threads, each one reading a separate file and add each character to a string.

File 1:

```
t
0
i
s
0
0
0
t
e
0
t
```

File 2:

```
0
h
0
0
i
s
a
0
0
s
0
```

So the expected output of this should be 'thisisatest'.

I'm currently able to run the two threads and have each of them read their respective files, and I know I need to use a mutex lock() and unlock() to make sure only one thread is adding to the string at at time, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement it.

```
mutex m;
int i = 0;
string s = "";

void *readFile(string fileName) {
    ifstream file;

    char a;

    file.open(fileName);
    if(!file) {
        cout << "Failed to open file." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while(file >> a) {
        if(a == '0') {

        } else {
            s += a;
        }
    }
}
int main() {

    thread p1(readFile, "Person1");
    thread p2(readFile, "Person2");

    p1.join();
    p2.join();

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried placing the m.lock() just inside the while() loop and having the m.unlock() nested in the if() statement, but it did not work. Currently my code will just output file1 with no zeros and file2 with no zeros concatenated (not in any particular order since there's no way to predict which thread completes first).

I want the program to look at the text file, check the character on the current line, and if it's a letter, concatenate it to the string s, and if it's a zero, pause this thread and let the other thread check it's line.

Comment: Do you want to train your multi-threading skills? Because if not, a single threaded approach for this problem would be superior...

Comment: Do you mind getting an answer that doesn't use threads?  You really do not need them and the solution is quite simple without them.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, this is for a challenge to practice using threads and mutex's so we must read each file using a unique thread. But you're right that it's a rather trivial problem without the challenge requirements.

Comment: @DrewPesall That's a shame.  This exercise is very ill suited for multithreading and all it will serve to do is teach you how not to multithread.

Comment: You'd probably use a condition variable; once seeing a null, the thread first notifies the other thread and then waits itself for getting notified. Very first time seeing a null notification would need to be skipped (the other thread then already *is* running).

Comment: @NathanOliver, Actually, an exercise of this type _does_ teach them something about how to coordinate the activity of two or more threads. The problem is, it teaches how to do it while giving them exactly the wrong idea about _when_ to do it.

Comment: @DrewPesall, The _best_ way to ensure that any program does certain things in a specific order is to have it do all of those things in a single thread. The best way to make use of threads is to let them run independently of one another for as long as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure the two threads run in sync, taking turns reading one line at a time. When a `0` is read, skip the turn, otherwise print the value.

For that you can use:

- A variable shared between the worker threads, to keep track of turns;
- A condition variable to notify threads of turn change;
- A mutex to make the condition variable work.

Here's a working example demonstrating the turn-taking approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cond;
    int turn = 0;
    auto task = [&](int myturn, int turns) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        while (turn < 9) {
            cond.wait(lock, [&] { return turn % turns == myturn; });
            std::cout << "Task " << myturn << std::endl;
            turn++;
            cond.notify_all();
        }
    };
    std::thread p1(task, 0, 2);
    std::thread p2(task, 1, 2);

    p1.join();
    p2.join();

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Task 0
Task 1
Task 0
Task 1
Task 0
Task 1
Task 0
Task 1
Task 0
Task 1
Done
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the index position in the string where each letter must go is predetermined and easily calculated from the data.

The thread which reads the second file:

```
0
h
0
0
i
s
```

knows that it is not responsible for the characters at `str[0]`, `str[2]` and `str[3]`, but is responsible for `str[1]`, `str[4]` and `str[5]`.

If we add a mutex and a condition variable, the algorithm is straightforward.

```
index = 0
while reading a line from the file succeeds: {
  if the line isn't "0": {
     lock(mutex)
     while length(str) < index: {
        wait(condition, mutex)
     }
     assert(length(str) == index)
     add line[0] to end of str
     unlock(mutex)
     broadcast(condition)
  }
  index++
}
```

Basically, for each character that the thread needs to write, it knows the index. It waits for the string to get that long first, which the other thread(s) will do. Whenever a thread adds a character, it broadcasts the condition variable, to wake up another thread which wants to put a character at the new index.

The `assert` check should never go off, unless the data is bad (tells two or more threads to place a character at the same index).  Also, if all threads hit a `0` line at the same index, of course, this will deadlock; every thread will be waiting for another thread to put a character at that index.

Another solution is possible using a synchronization object called a barrier. This problem is perfect for barriers, because what we have is a group of threads working through some tuples of data in parallel. For each tuple, exactly one thread must take action.

The algorithm is something like this:

```
// initialization:
init(barrier, 2)  // number of threads


// each thread:
while able to read line from file: {
   if line is not "0":
     append line[0] to str
   wait(barrier)
}
```

What `wait(barrier)` does is delay execution until 2 threads call it (because we initialized it to 2).  When this happens, all threads are released. Then the barrier resets itself for the next `wait`, whereupon it will wait for 2 threads again.

Thus, the execution is serialized: the threads execute the loop body in lock step as they march through the file. That thread which reads a character instead of `0` adds it to the string. The other threads don't touch the string; they proceed straight to the barrier wait, so there is no data race.